# Google Calendar API - I am able to create google meet conference link and send invite too - I would like them to add automatically to call

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-meet

I am using google calendar API to create calendar event along with Google meet conference link. I am able to send the invite to a guest; However, I would like to add them automatically to the conference link whenever they click on the link at the scheduled time without organizer accept/decline option. Can anybody suggest me what will be parameter I need to send to the API's

Comment: Are you referring to [Quick access](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2020/12/quick-access-calendar-event-google.html)? I don't think you can turn this option on/off via API. If that's not what you have in mind, can you provide more information about your current situation?

Comment: Well, I am using the API's to create google meet conference link via organizer mail ID, However to start the conference and add every attendee, organizer must need to open the conference link and allow access to every attendee, Here I don't want this flow irrespective of organizer every attendee can join the conference and start the communication.

Comment: AFAIK if guests are added to a scheduled event in Google Calendar, then as long as the guest is invited via their Gmail/Workspace address, as long as they are logged in they shouldn't need to be accepted. Can you show how you're setting up the conference link?